# Rails Cookies not Saving - Guest Devise User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, cookies, devise

I am following Devise approach to create Guest users for my Rails App, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

I am using cookies instead of sessions (as below code), to try to maintain same user per client devise, however when I close the browser and open again the cookie is not saved and a new User is created. I have tried it on Chrome and Firefox and same behavior is on both.

```
def create_guest_user
  u = User.new(:name => "guest", :email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(100)}@example.com", guest: true)
  u.save!(:validate => false)
  cookies.signed.permanent[:guest_user_id] = u.id
  u
end
```

When I check the session expiry on chrome, its browser close not permanent as it should be. I also tried to explicitly set expiry date but still getting same issue

[image]

Does anyone have an idea about the problem and possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
response.set_cookie(:guest_user_id, {
  value: u.id,
  path: '/',                 # cookie remains all pages in this domain
  expires: 2.weeks.from_now, # cookie expires after 2 week
  httponly: true,            # prevent javascript modify this cookie
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but still same behavior applies. Have you tried it before? Do you know maybe  if there is other config that should be done ?